# Error 502 in OpenOfficeSpreadsheet formula

Tags: script, openoffice, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

The formula failing is the following:

```
=IF(TIMEVALUE(C2 & ":00") > TIMEVALUE(B2 & ":00"); 0; C2-B2)
```

I previously tried

```
=IF(C2 > B2; 0; C2-B2)
```

but this also gives me "Error 502".

The cells it is referring to contains data in the format "12:30" (I formatted the columns with format "HH:MM").

I just want to calculate how much time lies between two times, respecting the special case where endtime < starttime.

Comment: It would help if you can explain what you want this formula to do.

Comment: if the second cell has the later time it should return 0, otherwise is should return the time difference in hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OpenOffice.org 3.1.1 with the following data:

```
Start          End            Elapsed
12:30:00 PM    05:30:00 PM    05:00:00
08:30:00 AM    05:30:00 PM    09:00:00
08:30:00 AM    08:00:00 AM    00:00:00
```

I used the following formula for the *Elapsed* column:

```
=IF(B2 < A2; 0; B2-A2)
```

*Start* and *End* use the formatting:

```
HH:MM:SS
```

And for the *Elapsed* column, I used

```
[HH]:MM
```

This seems to give the results you want.

Comment: But I cannot use AM/PM. The data is in the format I explained.

Comment: You have to either use 24-hour time, or use AM/PM. Otherwise it will just be a guessing game as to what was meant. If you change the formats in example above, it still works. Where is there problem?

Comment: thanks it works now it was the format code I used HH:MM for result instead of [HH]:MM